# Redundant string interpolation and performance

Tags: c#, performance, string-formatting

I've been doing some code refactoring in my C# projects.
I got a Resharper code analysis warning:

> "Redundant string interpolation"

This happens in following scenario:

```
void someFunction(string param)
{
...
}

someFunction($"some string");
```

I've read string interpolation is rewritten to `string.Format` at compile time. Then I tried following:

```
someFunction(string.Format("some string"));
```

This time I get:

> Redundant string.Format call.

My question is: Except the code cleanness, is the run-time performance affected by these redundant calls or the performance is the same for:

```
 someFunction($"some string")
 someFunction("some string")  
 someFunction(string.Format("some string"))
```

Comment: mostly cause you don't have any variable data other than a static string in your input  parameter

Comment: " performance is the same for:" Why not **measure**? Use a `StopWatch`, execute those statements some millions of times and compare the results. Have a look at https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: @Rahul The question apparently isn´t why ReShaprer is suggesting that hint, but what the performance-implication would be.

Comment: The issue I would suggest with the second and third forms is not the **runtime performance** but the cognitive load. In other words, people **don't commonly write code like that**. So whenever something weird, like `$"bob"` is used then the reader of the code is going to have to pause to think about it. If you used the normal (first) form **you know it will perform as fast as possible**, plus no extraneous cognitive load. And that is _best_ case scenario. Worst case scenario is they need to spend time 'cleaning' up your code, or coming over to you to ask why you did it this weird way.

Comment: @HimBromBeere: sparing a couple of allocations + parsing + copying by omitting a character from your source code is a no-brainer. While experienced programmers should avoid premature and micro optimizations, they should still be aware of the implications of these tiny choices. This is a perfectly valid question, the OP didn't make up the resharper warning, and it turns out that it doesn't affect performance in one case, but produces 40x slower code in the other one.

Comment: @Groo I never said the question isn´t valid. I just pointed out that optimizing the code just because you **can** isn´t a good idea and should instead be considered from a broader perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's perform a benchmark:

```
private static long someFunction(string value) {
  return value.Length;
}

...

Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

int n = 100_000_000;
long sum = 0;

sw.Start();

for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
  // sum += someFunction("some string");
  // sum += someFunction($"some string");
  sum += someFunction(string.Format("some string"));
}

sw.Stop();

Console.Write(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

**Outcome** (.Net 4.8 IA-64 Release), average results:

```
 224 // "some string"
 225 // $"some string"
8900 // string.Format("some string")
```

So we can see, that compiler removes unwanted `$` but executes `string.Format` which wastes time to understand that we don't have any formatting

Answer (score 7):

As the author of [that specific optimization](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/26612) in the C# compiler, I can confirm that `$"some string"` is optimized to `"some string"` by the C# compiler. That's a constant, and so virtually no code needs to execute at runtime to calculate it.

On the other hand, `string.Format("some string")` is a method invocation, and the method has to be invoked at runtime. Obviously, there is a cost associated with that call. It won't do anything useful of course, hence the warning "Redundant string.Format call."

Update: in fact, interpolations without fill-ins have always been optimized to the resulting string by the compiler. All it does is unescape `{{` to `{` and `}}` to `}`. My change was to optimize interpolations where all fill-ins are strings without formatting to string concatenations.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `string.Format("some string")` does a bunch of things, even if there are no formatting arguments after the format string.

Since there is no `string.Format` overload with only a single parameter, the runtime will first need to instantiate an empty params array (`new object[0]`) to pass it to the method. Then it will acquire an internal `StringBuilder` instance from a pool, and start parsing the format string, looking for placeholders. If you have a placeholder in your format string, but no argument, an exception is thrown, so the method always parses the format string.

Finally, the `StringBulder` will have to instantiate a new `string` and copy its contents there before being returned to the pool.

Based on @Dmitry's profiling, with an "empty" `FormattableString`, the compiler is likely smart enough to skip this whole process and just pass the string, since the contents of the string are evaluated during compile time to transform the interpolated literal into a `FormattableString` instance.

> I've heard string interpolation is rewritten to `string.Format` at compile time

This depends; if your function accepted a `FormattableString` parameter instead, then the compiler would create an instance of a class derived from `FormattableString` which would contain the formating string and an array of parameters. This can be useful for stuff like conditional debugging, because you don't pay the cost of formatting the string if it's not needed, i.e.:

```
 public void Log_A(string input)
 {
     if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
         Log.Debug(input);
 }

 public void Log_B(FormattableString input)
 {
     if (Log.IsDebugEnabled)
         Log.Debug(input.ToString());
 }

 // string.Format is called before entering Log_A
 Log_A($"Something happened with {x} and {y}");

 // if Log.IsDebugEnabled is false, string.Format will not be called
 Log_B($"Something happened with {x} and {y}");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void XYZ()
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        someFunction("some string");
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset();

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        someFunction("$some string");
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset();

    sw.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        someFunction(string.Format("some string"));
    }
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    sw.Reset();
}

private void someFunction(string param)
{
}
```

gives me

```
3
3
210
```

So, do not use string.Format() if you don't have to :-)

Comment: Avoid writing your own micro-benchmarking code, it will give incorrect results most of the time, make a habit of nuget-ing `BenchmarkDotNet` instead.